# Hacer aparecer elemento al hacer un hover

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, quasar

no sé como hacer aparecer un elemento al hacer hover sobre él, ya que este se encuentra interno dentro de un btn-toogle, mi código es el siguiente:

```
     <q-btn-toggle v-model="panelSelected" spread no-caps toggle-color="red" @click="redirecciona(panelSelected)"
              color="white" text-color="black" :options="panelesDisponibles">
                    <template  v-for="(x, key) in panelesDisponibles" :key="key" v-slot:[x.slot]>
                          <div class="btnPanel row items-center no-wrap">
                                <div id="buttonPanel">{{ x.modulos }}</div>
                                <q-tooltip>{{x.modulos + ' ' + x.contado  }}</q-tooltip>
                          </div>
                    </template>
        </q-btn-toggle>
```

necesito que el elemento "btnPanel" aparezca cuando poso el hover sobre el btn-toggle, no sé como realizar dicha acción

Answer (score 1):

Buenas puedes provar con la propiedad onmouseover:

```
<q-btn-toggle onmouseover="mostrar(this)" onmouseout="nomostrar(this)">
    ...
</q-btn-toggle>

<script>
   function mostrar(x){
       document.getElementById(x).style.display = "block";
   }
   function nomostrar(x){
       document.getElementById(x).style.display = "none";
   }
</script>
```

Espero haverte ayudado.